# Filter records in a list based on DateTime in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my list I want to find the recent and the most transacted branch based on datetime.ie: A branch which has got 100 deposits in the last  2 months would come first comparing to a bank which has about 150 deposits in the last 5 months

```
     List<Branches> _branches = new List< Branches >
                {
                    new Branch
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Branch:1",
                        Deposits = new List<Deposit>(){
                        new Deposit{
                            Id=1,
                            DateOfDeposit="01/01/2016",
                            Amount=50
                        },
    ,
                        new Deposit{
                            Id=2,
                            DateOfDeposit="05/02/2017",
                            Price=30
                        },
                        new Deposit{
                            Id=3,
                            DateOfDeposit="01/01/2017",
                            Price=30
                        }
                    }
                    },continues...
```

Comment: @Peter Bons Tried group by and order by to get the count but, could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are comparing can't be done.  You are asking to change two comparisons at the same time.  You can only compare items with the same criteria.  Using code below will get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Branch> branches = new List<Branch>() {
                new Branch() {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Branch:1",
                    Deposits = new List<Deposit>(){
                        new Deposit{
                            Id=1,
                            DateOfDeposit = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2016","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Amount=50
                        },
                        new Deposit() {
                            Id=2,
                            DateOfDeposit = DateTime.ParseExact("05/02/2017","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Amount = 30
                        },
                        new Deposit() {
                            Id=3,
                            DateOfDeposit = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2017","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Amount = 30
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Branch() {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Branch:2",
                    Deposits = new List<Deposit>() {
                        new Deposit{
                            Id=1,
                            DateOfDeposit = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2016","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Amount=50
                        },
                        new Deposit() {
                            Id=2,
                            DateOfDeposit = DateTime.ParseExact("05/02/2017","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Amount = 30
                        },
                        new Deposit() {
                            Id=3,
                            DateOfDeposit = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2017","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Amount = 30
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var results = branches.Select(x => new {
                Id = x.Id,
                month1Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)).Count(),
                month2Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)).Count(),
                month3Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)).Count(),
                month4Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-4)).Count(),
                month5Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-5)).Count(),
                month6Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)).Count(),
                month7Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-7)).Count(),
                month8Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-8)).Count(),
                month9Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-8)).Count(),
                month10Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-10)).Count(),
                month11Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-11)).Count(),
                month12Deposits = x.Deposits.Where(y => y.DateOfDeposit >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)).Count()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Branch
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public List<Deposit> Deposits { get; set;}

    }
    public class Deposit
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public DateTime  DateOfDeposit { get; set;}
        public int Amount { get; set;}
    }

}
```